# How to sync tables schema without dropping the table?

Tags: sql, database

Not:

```
DROP -> CREATE
```

I need:

```
COMPARE -> ALTER
```

I have a test and a production database, the data withing these two are different but the schemas should be the same.
I need something like a **production script** or a tool or a method which compare these two dbs schema and sync them. I'm coding in **nodejs** and the thing is I haven't used tools like an ORM or `db-migrate`, I've created the database using `MYSQL-workbench` and it costs a lot to write every alter query. there must be an easier way.

Comment: Why not just delete the test database and recreate it by copying the production?  Trying to put incremental changes in just seems like a recipe for getting them out-of-synch.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the point is I'm developing on the test db and the changes on tables will happen there. So once I satisfy with a version, I want to update the production schema to look exactly the same as test.

Comment: . . Then delete production and replace it with test.

Comment: Wouldn't reccomend deleting prod